# Can we loop over a map using size and for loop

Tags: java, hashmap

I've the below code.

```
String[] guest1 = { "surfing", "yoga", "walking" };
String[] guest2 = { "wine", "relaxation", "beach" };

ArrayList<String> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
list1.add("museums");
list1.add("canals");
list1.add("nightlife");
list1.add("walking");
ArrayList<String> list2 = new ArrayList<>();
list2.add("beach");
list2.add("surfing");
list2.add("relaxation");
ArrayList<String> list3 = new ArrayList<>();
list3.add("surfing");
list3.add("nightlife");
list3.add("beach");
list3.add("food");
list3.add("wine");
list3.add("walking");

String[] sagres = { "beach", "surfing", "relaxation" };
String[] biarritz = { "surfing", "nightlife", "beach", "food", "wine", "walking" };

Map map = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>();
map.put("amsterdam", list1);
map.put("sagres", list2);
map.put("biarritz", list3);

for (int i = 0; i < map.size(); i++) {
    System.out.println(map.keySet());
}
```

Here I'm trying to get the key and the values by looping on the size.

I know that this can be done using

```
for (Object keys : map.keySet().toArray()) {
    System.out.println(keys);
}
```

But I have to compare 2 values at a time and work accordingly. I want to know if I can use the `size` and loop.

Thanks

Comment: Change it to `map.entrySet()`. Then iterate using `Map.Entry<K,V>`

Comment: explain what you want to compare exactly

Comment: @NicolasFilotto, I want to compare the data in map(1) with map(2), map(2) with map(3) and finally map(3) with map(1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code gets the entry set of the `Map`. It then iterates over that entire set and prints out the keys and values, separated by a comma and a tab character. Since `entry.getValue()` returns a `List<String>`, it needs to be converted to a `String` for concatenation.

```
for (Map.Entry<String, List<String>> entry : map.entrySet()) {
    System.out.println(entry.getKey() + ", \t" + entry.getValue().toString());
}
```

Also, general practice says to use `List` instead of `ArrayList` when declaring a `List`. This way, it preserves polymorphism. Regarding the comparisons, you are unclear on what you are trying to compare, so I cannot really give an answer on that.

Comment: Hi @ifly6, I get this Exception `Type mismatch: cannot convert from element type Object to Map.Entry<String,List<String>>`

Comment: Change `Map map = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>();` to `Map<String, List<String>> map = new HashMap<>();`

Answer (score 0):

The iterator may fulfill a similar role as index.

```
Iterator<Map.Entry<String, ArrayList<String>> iter1 = map.entrySet().iterator();
Iterator<Map.Entry<String, ArrayList<String>> iter2 = map.entrySet().iterator();

while (iter1.hasNext() || iter2.hasNext()) {
    ...
    if (iter1.hasNext()) {
        entry1 = iter1.next();
    } 
}
```

By the way it is more conventional and less typing to write as follows:

```
List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
Map<String, List<String>> map = new HashMap<>();
```

That is specify variables as interfaces, and leave the specific implementing class open. Ideal for method parameters too.

Comment: Just a typo, `Internator`.

Comment: Maybe it interns things? :P

Comment: @JoopEggen It's like the Terminator but instead of killing people it replaces them with exact replicas from a standard pool.